# jqplot pie chart not showing all available values

Tags: jqplot, pie-chart

I need some help related with jqPlot pie-chart value. Using the following data-set:

```
['XX01',77.28], ['XX02',3.28], ['XX03',3.31], ['XX04',2.42], ['XX05',2.4],
['XX06',1.61], ['XX07',2.45], ['XX08',1.69], ['XX09',2.18], ['XX10',1.6],
['XX11',1.78]
```

and this jqPlot option script:

```
seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
    rendererOptions: {
        showDataLabels: true,
        dataLabels: 'value',
        dataLabelFormatString: '%.2f%%',
        dataLabelPositionFactor: 1.2,
        shadow: false,
        sliceMargin: 3
    },
}
```

the result is not showing **all** the available values. see the [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yhyB.jpg).

Can somebody help me about this? Waiting for any solution here... thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the response, Nandu.

I just figured it out yesterday, there is plugin's option for the data label, it is called `dataLabelThreshold` - [jqPlot documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pieRenderer-js.html#%24.jqplot.PieRenderer.dataLabelThreshold). By default the value is `3`, which mean that for any value below 3 won't be displayed. So the solutions just as simple as define the new threshold.

Answer (score 0):

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NYewy/320/)

```
$.jqplot('pieChart', [[['XX01',7.28], ['XX02',3.28], ['XX03',3.31], ['XX04',2.42], ['XX05',2.4],
['XX06',1.61], ['XX07',2.45], ['XX08',1.69], ['XX09',2.18], ['XX10',1.6],
['XX11',1.78]]],
{
seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
    rendererOptions: {
        showDataLabels: true,
        dataLabels: 'value',       
        dataLabelFormatString: '%.2f%%',
        dataLabelPositionFactor: 1.2,
        shadow: false,
        sliceMargin: 3
    },
}
});
```

I think it is due to your data.I changed the first data from **77.28** to **7.28**.It works fine.

Comment: well, changing the data value is not the solution. as I answered the question, you can see the better solution there.